# Angular 2 create a configuration file like Laravel

Tags: angular, configuration-files

I am from `Laravel` background and i want to use the feature of generating a configuration file in `Angular 2` as we can do in `Laravel`.

We could create a configuration file in `config` folder and start using it there.

**How could we create a configuration file in `Angular 2`?**

As i cannot find any good information on this topic.

Hope i have given required information on the question. Will update the question if any more information is required.

Comment: You could make a shared service containing those settings.

Comment: Have you tried Angular CLI , it has environment based configs?